# javac installed in /etc

Tags: java, etc

I have installed `openjdk-9-jdk:amd64` on Ubuntu and when I run `which javac` it shows me a softlink leading to the `/etc` directory:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 kwi 13 08:09 /usr/bin/javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac
```

As far as I know only configuration data should be stored in `/etc`. Why is `javac` stored there and should I move this executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `/etc/alternatives` you’ll see it doesn’t contain executables, but more symlinks; for example

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Sep 20  2016 /etc/alternatives/javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

This is how alternatives are implemented: the “binary” in the path is a symlink to the alternative in `/etc/alternative`, which is itself a symlink to the chosen target binary. This selection *is* configuration data, so `/etc` is perfectly appropriate. (Alternatives can be used for more than binaries, so you’ll find manpages etc. in there too.)